# MongoDB: How i run this query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have many keys like the follwing:

```
foo.bar.N.taz.M.zat = value
```

where N and M are random integers.

How i can search for a value in a structure like that?

Comment: Could you give us additional information? How is the key generated? What is your document structure/ can you provide a sample document? What values are you attempting to find? Any additional information about the requirements of your query will help us provide an efficient solution.

Comment: But in general, you should store data that you'd like to query as the value rather than the key, e.g. {key: "foo.bar.N.taz.M.zat", value: x}